# Debug tox unit tests with visual studio code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, tox, vscode-python

I am trying to debug an existing set of unit tests that are run with tox. I updated my launch.json file to include the following configuration:

```
{
     "module": "tox",
     "name": "tox unit tests",
     "request": "launch",
     "type": "python",
     "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

The tests run within vscode integrated terminal, but any breakpoints I set do not get hit so it doesn't seem like I have everything quite right.

How can I be able to catch breakpoints within my code?

Here is an example of one test structure:

```
class TestController(TestCase):
    @patch("server.services.get", "")
    def test_handle_item(self, mock_get):
        a = controller.handle_item(MOCK_ID)
        self.assertEqual(a, 2)
```